# how to change which element parsley-error is added to

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I'm working with parsley.j and when an error happens it adds a parsley-error class to the input element. Is there a way to change this so it adds it to another element up the chain.

```
<div class="control-group email">
 <div class="controls"><div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on">
  </span>
  <input class="string email optional input parsley-validated parsley-error" data- trigger="change" data-type="email" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="Enter your email" size="200" type="text" value="">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to add the parsley-error class to the first div  instead of the input class.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#parsleyclasses, you could via a callback function determine in Parsley config, on which dom element you whant Parsley to put the error/success classes

```
$('#form').parsley( {
    errors: {
        classHandler: function ( elem, isRadioOrCheckbox ) {
            return $( elem ).parent();
        }
    }
} );
```

If you do so, please not that you'll need to remove the `data-validate="parsley"` attribute.

You could also use the listeners, `onFieldError` and `onFieldSuccess` to add you proper class on the div you want.